# Count unique rows in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some trouble figuring out a SQL Server query. The relational model is quite old (it seems) and is not very optimal, to say the least.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [RequestUsers].requestId, [Requests].name, [Requests].isBooked
FROM 
    [RequestUsers]
JOIN 
    [Requests] ON [RequestUsers].requestId = [Requests].id
WHERE 
    [RequestUsers].dateRequested >= '10-01-2013'
    AND [RequestUsers].dateRequested <= '10-16-2013'
```

This query gives a result of loads of duplicated records, i.e.:

```
id      name        isBooked
-----------------------------
1393    Request1       0
1393    Request1       0
1393    Request1       0    
1394    Request2       0
1394    Request2       0
1399    Request3       0
1399    Request3       0
1399    Request3       0
1399    Request3       0
1399    Request3       0
```

(I omitted lots of records here)

My question is: is there any way to modify the above query to group the duplicated records and make a `requestCount` column which holds the number of duplicates? Like this:

```
id      name        isBooked     requestCount
---------------------------------------------
1393    Request1       0              3
1399    Request2       0              2
1393    Request3       0              5
```

? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the relational model being old have to do with how you write your SQL queries or how fast they run (if that's what you mean with "optimal")?

Comment: And `RequestUsers.requestId = RequestUsers.id`? It doesn't look right. I guess you meant `RequestUsers.requestId = Requests.id` No wonder you have duplicates if you don't join to `Requests` properly.

Comment: Easy, easy :-) That was a typo here on stackoverflow. Sorry about that! By the way: it has nothing to do with me writing queryies, but I think the relational modal could be made better than it is. That's all!

Comment: Probably irrelevant but you shouldn't use date literals with this (`'MM-DD-YYYY'`) format. It's not at all clear that `10-01-2013` is October 1st or January 10th. Use the `'YYYYMMDD'` format for input as it's the only 100% safe one. See **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Comment: Nope, I just figured when trying the query in C# :-) Thanks!

Comment: I still fail to see how the relational model is related to the question/discussion here. Unless with "relational model" you mean something else, like SQL.

Comment: Not going to make a huge discussion out of this really, but I honestly think that this is a bit of a hacky way to get the number of requests from a given date span. I think the table structure could be better from the very beginning to make such queries easier and more delicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT [RequestUsers].requestId, 
       [Requests].name, 
       [Requests].isBooked,
       Count(*) AS requestCount
FROM   [RequestUsers]
       JOIN [Requests]
           ON [RequestUsers].requestId = [Requests].id
WHERE  [RequestUsers].dateRequested >= '10-01-2013'
       AND [RequestUsers].dateRequested <= '10-16-2013'
GROUP BY [RequestUsers].requestId, 
       [Requests].name, 
       [Requests].isBooked
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [RequestUsers].requestId, [Requests].name, [Requests].isBooked,
COUNT([RequestUsers].requestId) "requestCount"
FROM [RequestUsers]
JOIN [Requests]
ON [RequestUsers].requestId = [RequestUsers].id
WHERE [RequestUsers].dateRequested >= '10-01-2013'
AND [RequestUsers].dateRequested <= '10-16-2013'
GROUP BY [RequestUsers].requestId, [Requests].name, [Requests].isBooked
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT Distinct([RequestUsers].requestId), [Requests].name, [Requests].isBooked, Count([RequestUsers].requestId) as requestCount
    FROM [RequestUsers]
    JOIN [Requests]
    ON [RequestUsers].requestId = [RequestUsers].id
    WHERE [RequestUsers].dateRequested >= '10-01-2013'
    AND [RequestUsers].dateRequested <= '10-16-2013'
    GROUP BY [RequestUsers].requestId
```